# libvirtd: kvm: User Permissions Centos 6

Tags: centos, permissions, kvm-virtualization, user-management, virsh

I need to have user access control over how they can use the Virtual machines and what they can do via Virsh on a KVM based hypervisor.

So far what I learned from http://wiki.libvirt.org is that I have to enable the unix socket permissions at `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf` for the unix socket and create a new group called libvirtd and add users into that. So that went all fine, however, with those users I can't see any virtual machines when I do

`virsh list --all`

The documentation at libvirt.ogr also mentions using polkit and other techniques.

If someone could help me with any working example of either using simple `unix socket permission` method or `polikit` or `sudoer` method or any other method.

I would like have user permissions in such a way that a user from virsh can perform only limited tasks such as cant do `virsh start` but can't `virsh destroy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. The easiest and simplest solution is sudoers. We can do lot of stuff with sudoers regular expressions. I simply added one sudoer rule.

Keep all the guest machines name in such a way that you could specify them using some kind of regex. In my case I kept all guest machines, those I want to be controller by non root users, starting with vmname-.

Below rule would allow non root users to start and get the console the vm and wont allow to destroy it.

```
Cmnd_Alias KVMCMD = /usr/bin/virsh list --all,/usr/bin/virsh start vmname*
Cmnd_Alias KVMBAD = virsh destroy vmname*
```

Hope this helps someone who is looking for similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had success with using PolicyKit on CentOS 6.5 using the libvirt wiki:

http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/SSHPolicyKitSetup

The missing step to getting it to work with `virsh:` is to add the following to your .bash_profile:

```
if test -x `which virsh`; then
  export LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI=qemu:///system
fi
```

(this is from this [post](http://www.linuxsysadmintutorials.com/configure-polkit-to-run-virsh-as-a-normal-user/))

This setup also allows pretty seamless usage from virt-manager on a remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

For proper RBAC you will need a more sophisticated VM management platform than libvirt, which is there to control VM lifecycle, and little else really. Take a look at oVirt.org for a good example

Comment: I found out that it will be possible with sudoers, however, not sure how to get variable arugument work. Cases like virsh start $vm-name.